# FlipView is not accessible in simple WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, flipview

Windows has this beautiful control [FlipView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flipview.aspx).

When I want to add it to my xaml page, VS can find it source (I've checked, Windows library is included into project). So I found suggestion to create own class which will be inherited from `FlipView` class. After I did it, VS said it can't find definition of `<FlipView.ItemTemplate>`. So what I am doing wrong?

---

Code which I've used to test FlipView

```
  <FlipView x:Name="flipView1" Width="480" Height="270" 
          BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Image Width="480" Height="270" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                    <Border Background="#A5000000" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="26.667" 
                                   Foreground="#CCFFFFFF" Padding="15,20"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlipView is a Windows Store/Universal App only class.

The page you link to clearly states:

> Requirements (Windows 10 device family)
>
> **Device family**
> Universal

and

> Requirements (Windows 8.x and Windows Phone 8.x)
>
> **Minimum supported client**
> Windows 8 [Windows Store apps only]

If you want to have the same functionality in a WPF desktop application you will need to either find a third party control that does the same or write your own.

Comment: oh :( I understand. Would try to find other solutions